# React Hooks state not working properly when the function calling it is called in another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this component using Hooks:

```
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState({ h1: "hello", h2: "hi" });

  const changeH1 = () => {
    setText({
      ...text,
      h1: text.h1 + "C"
    });
  };

  const changeH2 = () => {
    setText({
      ...text,
      h2: text.h2 + "X"
    });
  };

  const changeAll = () => {
    changeH1();
    changeH2();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={() => changeH1()}>{text.h1}</h1>
      <h1 onClick={() => changeH2()}>{text.h2}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => changeAll()}>Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It will display two headings with some text and a button. When I click on the first heading, the "C" character will be added to the heading. When I click on the second heading, the "X" character will be added to the heading. When I click the button, it will do two actions above at the same time.

It works fine on two headings but the button. When I click the button, only the second heading changes. I think that the `setText` of `changeH1` and `changeH2` are not working when they are called in `changeAll`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: <button onClick={() => changeAll}>Change</button> try to replace changeAll by changeAll()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `changeH2()` overwrites `h1` property by doing `...text`.

The 2 `setText()` calls are executed before a re-render - I believe it's due to batching as explained in https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/#batching

A solution would be to use a simple state instead of an object:

```js
  const [h1, setH1] = useState("hello");
  const [h2, setH2] = useState("hi");
  ...
```

Or else `useReducer` for more complex operations https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer